# Multimedia Keys not working?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, multimedia

I have tried out Keytouch and successfully created a new keyboard file and also successfully applied it. But still my multimedia keys are not working. I am using lubuntu 14.04 and audacious for audio and gnome mplayer for video. Please help me out here please.

Thank you.

Comment: I found out that multimedia keys don't work with audacious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess currently multimedia keys work with rhythmbox, but not audacious or banshee.

Comment: Why is this the best answer? This is actually a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In Audacious I was going to <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>General Tab</kbd> -> And enabled check at "Gnome Shortcuts".

All of my multimedia keys now work with Audacious.  :)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In Audacious plugins settings you can try to enable "Global Hotkeys" and "MPRIS 2 Server".